# Mistake on back of check

Tags: personal-check

If I signed over a check mailed to me to my daughter but made a mistake can I cross her name out and initial it so I can cash like I was going to

Comment: @prl To me it sounds like OP received a check payable to the OP. The OP signed the endorsement area on the back and wrote in the name of the OP's daughter, so she would be able to deposit it in her account (as per [How to Sign/Endorse a Check Over to Someone Else](https://www.huntington.com/Personal/checking/how-to-sign-a-check-over-to-someone). The OP has now changed their mind, and no longer wishes to sign it over to their daughter.  Lachelle: can you confirm if my interpretation is correct?

Comment: Checks / cheques work differently in different places. Are you in the US?